# globally change URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I recently made a site where the base url looks like

[www.example.com/myExample](http://www.example.com/myExample)

And my controller is called myExample.

But my boss wants me to change it to

[www.example.com/my_example](http://www.example.com/my_example)

I'm assuming this is something that can be done with the routes, rather than renaming the controller file? But I haven't been able to figure out how.

Any direction is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the codeigniter 3 [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=translate_uri_dashes).
In your `application/config/routes.php file`

```
$route['journals'] = 'blogs';
```

A URL containing the word “journals” in the first segment will be remapped to the “blogs” class.

So in your case it could be like

```
$route['my_example'] = 'myExample';
```

**Edit:**

Following routing rule should work fine for your situation, but understand  this as mentioned by another user in the comment, you will need to replace all the links that use `myExample` controller so that your incoming link should look like as your boss wants `www.example.com/my_example/somethingelse/anotherpage`. Now your Routing rule will first map the controller to `myExample` and map the first and second URI segments as `$1` and `$2` whatever that maybe.

```
$route['my_example/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'myExample/$1/$2';
```

Comment: so that works for just the home page, but if I have another page www.example.com/myExample/somethingelse/anotherpage is there a way to have it as www.example.com/my_example/somethingelse/anotherpage?

Comment: @xanabobana yes, you can map any routs that you want, even dynamic routs can be mapped. Just read the documentation I have included link to documentation in the answer.

Comment: I read the documentation but I'm not understanding.  I tried to use: $route['my_example/(:num)'] = 'myExample/$1'; to map all routes but that's not working.

Comment: @OmarAbbas You need to modify all internal link on your site to new URI segment schemas. (Or convince the boss that this renaming is not a good idea.)